# firebase function v2 trigger for realtimedatabase using a python script is not working for me

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to use python with firebase functions. I already have a function running for my webhooks. but I tried to add another function to run when a new record is created on RealtimeDatabase, without success.

I tried using the CLI at first, following the steps and using this code from the quickstart :

```
from typing import Any
# The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and set up triggers.
from firebase_functions import db_fn

# The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database.
from firebase_admin import initialize_app, db

app = initialize_app()


@db_fn.on_value_written(reference="/Stores/{storeID}")
def onwrittenfunctiondefault(event: db_fn.Event[db_fn.Change]) -> None:
    print(event.data)
```

You can see I switched to on_value_written to catch any change on the path Stores/{storeID}
I don't know what am i missing..

I also tried to create the function from google cloud console, created the eventarc trigger and it was deployed successfully. but when I add anything to the database, it is not triggered.

Does anyone have an idea what I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what i did :
I got owner permissions for my firebase account . ( maybe it is irrelevant! )
and I deleted my script, copied the full script from [quickstarts](https://github.com/firebase//functions-samples)

Now I can see in the logs that the function is triggered and working. However, when I tried to modify the path to be something like :  /messages/{pushId}/original/{type}
the function failed, it was triggered but failed.
adding {type} at the end was causing a problem. It wasn't a main requirement anyway .